# Como separar las palabras con una medida en un archivo de texto

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11

estoy realizando un archivo de texto donde pido el nombre, apellido, cedula y edad. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero en el archivo de texto no me imprime de una forma que se vea bien (es algo estético). Quiero que entre el nombre, apellido, cedula y edad tengan la misma separación.
Dejo la función que agrega estos datos y la imagen de como esta el txt.

```
void agregar(ofstream &archivo){
system("cls");
string nombre,apellido,cedula,edad;
archivo.open("Personas.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
cout<<"Digite el nombre: "<<endl;
cin>>nombre;
cout<<"Digite el apellido: "<<endl;
cin>>apellido;
cout<<"Digite la cedula: "<<endl;
cin>>cedula;
fflush(stdin);
cout<<"Digite la edad: "<<endl;
cin>>edad;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Personsa agregada con exito!!"<<endl;
cout<<endl<<endl;
archivo<<" "<<nombre<<"    "<<apellido<<"    "<<cedula<<"    "<<edad<<endl;
archivo.close();
}
```

**IMAGEN:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas o menos busco que en el txt quede así (eso lo hice agregando espacios):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el nombre y/o el apellido es de más de una palabra? P.E. *Juan Antonio* (nombre) *de todos los Santos* (primer apellido).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te conformas con alinear los valores a la derecha, puedes usar la librería iomanip:

```
#include <iomanip>

// ...

archivo << setw(15) << nombre   << ' '
        << setw(15) << apellido << ' '
        << setw(10) << cedula   << ' '
        << setw(2)  << edad     << '\n';
```

Este mecanismo también podrías usarlo para centrar los valores, pero el código se complica:

```
size_t nombre_size = (15 - nombre.length()) / 2 + nombre.length();
std::cout << std::setw(nombre_size ) << nombre << std::setw(15 - nombre_size) << "";

size_t apellido_size = (15 - apellido.length()) / 2 + apellido.length();
std::cout << std::setw(apellido_size ) << apellido << std::setw(15 - apellido_size ) << "";

// ...

std::string edad_str = std::to_string(edad);
size_t edad_size = (15 - edad_str .length()) / 2 + edad_str .length();
std::cout << std::setw(edad_size ) << edad_str << std::setw(15 - edad_size ) << "";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)